# How to create a horizontal sliding sub-menu panel for my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a horizontal sliding sub-menu for my site. When you click on the `Menu Item 2` then the sub-menu panel show/hide by sliding function or something like that.

Just for example, It's not like that I'm copyrighting or something - [GoDaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com/) navigation menu.

Here is my - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uX4c5/1/)

There are few things I want in this menu -

1. Fades out the whole page when menu expand.
2. When you click anywhere else then sub-menu on the fade out page, then sub-menu panel will auto collapse.
3. And it will also collapse when you click the same menu item again.
4. It will slideup and slidedown smoothly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="main-header" class="center">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" id="button" onclick="showhide()">Menu Item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sub-menu"><a href="#">Sub Menu Panel</a>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.center {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#header {
    background-color: #333333;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0px;
}
#main-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 115px;
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 85px;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #99FF00;
}
#sub-menu {
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#container {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #333333;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showhide() {
    var div = document.getElementById("sub-menu");
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Please help me using JavaScript or jQuery, I know that I'm missing the whole script but help me.

Comment: To get you started, have a look at [**CSS3 transitions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) using `opacity` and `durations`. You can apply different styles using transition, display and positioning and then use JavaScript to switch between the classes.

Comment: That's the main problem I'm not able to fit everything WORKING!

Comment: Just as a general side-note, saying `I don't want to mess up with jQuery` makes no sense. I'm **not** at all saying use jQuery. I'm simply pointing out that with jQuery you have this done in less time and require less JavaScript knowledge than just using JavaScript and it will be cross-browser compatible by design. (Ignoring CSS3 solutions). Anyway, I'm all for just using JavaScript and CSS so don't get me wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you never called your hiding function, so the sub-menu was never hidden. Second, here's an example I produced in about 2 minutes using jQuery to achieve what you have in mind. Here's the JS/jQuery:

```
function showhide(){
    var div = document.getElementById("sub-menu");
    if (div.style.display != "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
 }
// Calling the function
showhide();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu li:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
        $('#sub-menu').slideToggle(300);
    });
    $('a.close').click(function(){
        $('#sub-menu').slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uX4c5/4/

Comment: Thanks for help me. but this is not exactly what I'm looking for... I want it work by `OnClick` not hover and close when I click again on `Menu Item 2` not on `Sub Menu Panel (click to close)`. Can you plz update it...

Comment: I realized that after I posted and I edited the answer to reflect that. I've got the new fiddle posted there, too, but here's another one with the fade you asked for, too: http://jsfiddle.net/uX4c5/6/